# Writing the logic function for circuits

Tags: architecture, logic

As i mentioned in a previous question I'm fairly new to the world of programming and computers having just started a university coure.

I'm really struggling coming to terms with writing the logic function for circuits.

I was was wondering if anyone might have the logic function to these?

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/78651059@N07/7041822113/in/photostream
http://www.flickr.com/photos/78651059@N07/7041821965/in/photostream/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/78651059@N07/7041821833/in/photostream/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look to me like pretty straightforward translations of syntax. For example, in C, `XOR` is `^`, `AND` is `&` and `NOT` is `~`, so your first circuit would come out as:

```
Y = (A & ~B) ^ C;
```

The big difference is that C (like most normal programming languages) doesn't have any data type for a single bit, so this would really represent a minimum of 8 copies of the circuit in parallel (i.e., the data types of A, B, and C will normally be at least one byte apiece).

I won't go through the others, but I'd note that in many cases it's easiest to work your way backward from the output to the input rather than the (perhaps more obvious) route from input to output.

Edit: oops: kind of forgot to mention it, but in C, `OR` is `|`.

Edit: to simplify things, it may be easiest (at least as first) to write some small functions to act as logic gates:

```
int bitwise_and(int a, int b) {  return a & b); }
int bitwise_or(int a, int b)  {  return a | b;  }
int bitwise_not(int a)        {  return ~a;     }
int bitwise_xor(int a, int b) {  return a ^ b;  }
```

Then you can basically just turn a gate in a logic diagram into a function call, so for example, an OR gate taking A and B as inputs and producing Y as an output would become `Y = bitwise_or(a, b);`

Comment: So it would involve working out the truth table for each gate?

Comment: @Bananaco: The truth table? No, not usually anyway. You could do that when/if you wanted to simplify the circuit (but much of the time Demorgan's theorem is sufficient), but just converting to a programming language doesn't require that at all.

Comment: I'm still kind of stuck on this.

Comment: @Bananaco: I've edited a further suggestion into my answer.

Comment: :If I were to take the last link as an example as it looks the easiest. My understanding of it would be Y= (AB)B'. I am guessing that can't be right?

Comment: Hmm...A and B go to an OR gate, so that's `A | B`. The result of that and the inversion of B go to an AND gate, so you'd get `(A | B) & ~B`.

Comment: I may be starting to understand this now.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my :)

I used to do these when I was at University. A good starting point would be to start by writing the Boolean algebra formula for the circuit. Just keep it basic when you first begin, don't worry about reducing the formula until you have the full one written out.

If you have specific questions, or are stumped on a specific part of the circuit, I would be happy to help you out. Just find out where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: So just take each gate and write out the truth table for each one?

Comment: you want the equation of y or want to know what the circuit does @Bananaco?